# Reset counter used program line

Tags: counters, programming

I have a problem with how to reset the counter in a case where I am trying to print names in one row and the telephone numbers in another row. I know I could have avoided the problem, but it is required for the work I am doing.

Here is the result I have reached so far:

[image]

This is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\newcounter{faglig}\renewcommand{\thefaglig}{\alph{faglig}}
\makeatletter
\let\contactrow\@gobble
\let\telephonerow\@gobble
%\setcounter{faglig}{0}
%\stepcounter{faglig}
%\textsuperscript{\,\thefaglig}

\def\contact#1{%
\ifx\contactrow\@gobble\def\contactrow{\textbf {Person:}}\fi
\expandafter\def\expandafter\contactrow\expandafter{\contactrow\hspace{1cm}#1\stepcounter{faglig}\textsuperscript{\,\thefaglig}}}

\setcounter{faglig}{0}
\def\telephone#1{%
\ifx\telephonerow\@gobble\def\telephonerow{\textbf {Telephone:}}\fi
\expandafter\def\expandafter\telephonerow\expandafter{\telephonerow\hspace{1cm}#1\stepcounter{faglig}\textsuperscript{\,\thefaglig}}}
\makeatother


\contact{John Doe}
\telephone{12345}
\contact{Jane Doe}
\telephone{91145}
\contact{Donald Trump}
\telephone{67890}

\begin{document}

\contactrow
\newline

\telephonerow

\end{document}
```

The problem is how to reset the counter to have the telephone numbers indexed accordingly to the names. The command that I thought would reset does not seem to work. As you can see I have tried some alternatives that are commented out. If anyone have other comments to the code I would appreciated that too. I am all new to this type of programming, but it is very fun. I hope anyone can direct me in the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need no counter, but `expl3`. `;-)`

With `\seq_indexed_map_function:NN` we can use the index number of the items stored in a sequence.

I also added a macro to print the data in tabular form, just to make a different example.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_osterlie_contact_person_seq
\seq_new:N \g_osterlie_contact_telephone_seq

% store the items in the appropriate sequence
\NewDocumentCommand{\contact}{m}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_osterlie_contact_person_seq { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\telephone}{m}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_osterlie_contact_telephone_seq { #1 }
 }

% Deliver the names, with the index (in alphabetical form) as a superscript
\NewDocumentCommand{\contactrow}{}
 {
  Person:
  \seq_indexed_map_function:NN \g_osterlie_contact_person_seq \osterlie_contact_print:nn
 }

% Deliver the phone number, with the index (in alphabetical form) as a superscript
\NewDocumentCommand{\telephonerow}{}
 {
  Telephone:
  \seq_indexed_map_function:NN \g_osterlie_contact_telephone_seq \osterlie_contact_print:nn
 }

% Deliver the data in tabular form
\NewDocumentCommand{\contacts}{}
 {
  \begin{tabular}
   {
    @{}
    l
    *{\seq_count:N \g_osterlie_contact_person_seq}{c}
    @{}
   }
  Person:
  \seq_map_function:NN \g_osterlie_contact_person_seq \osterlie_contact_tabular:n
  \\
  Telephone:
  \seq_map_function:NN \g_osterlie_contact_telephone_seq \osterlie_contact_tabular:n
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_new:Nn \osterlie_contact_print:nn
 {
  \hspace{1cm}#2\textsuperscript{\int_to_alph:n{#1}}
 }

\cs_new:Nn \osterlie_contact_tabular:n
 {
  & #1
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\contact{John Doe}
\telephone{12345}
\contact{Jane Doe}
\telephone{91145}
\contact{Donald Trump}
\telephone{67890}

\begin{document}

\contactrow\par
\telephonerow

\bigskip

\contacts

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `\setcounter{faglig}{0}` is placed between the definitions of `\contactrow` and `\telephonerow`, this means it is executed before the document even starts and the counter is 0 anyway.

Place `\setcounter{faglig}{0}` instead at the start of the telephone row or between the lines where `\contactrow` and `\telephonerow` are used in the document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\newcounter{faglig}\renewcommand{\thefaglig}{\alph{faglig}}
\makeatletter
\let\contactrow\@gobble
\let\telephonerow\@gobble
%\setcounter{faglig}{0}
%\stepcounter{faglig}
%\textsuperscript{\,\thefaglig}

\def\contact#1{%
\ifx\contactrow\@gobble\def\contactrow{\textbf {Person:}}\fi
\expandafter\def\expandafter\contactrow\expandafter{\contactrow\hspace{1cm}#1\stepcounter{faglig}\textsuperscript{\,\thefaglig}}}


\def\telephone#1{%
\ifx\telephonerow\@gobble\def\telephonerow{\setcounter{faglig}{0}\textbf {Telephone:}}\fi
\expandafter\def\expandafter\telephonerow\expandafter{\telephonerow\hspace{1cm}#1\stepcounter{faglig}\textsuperscript{\,\thefaglig}}}
\makeatother


\contact{John Doe}
\telephone{12345}
\contact{Jane Doe}
\telephone{91145}
\contact{Donald Trump}
\telephone{67890}

\begin{document}

\contactrow
\newline

%\setcounter{faglig}{0}
\telephonerow

\end{document}
```

[image]